# animate opacity out, insert html, animate opacity in

Tags: jquery, animation, opacity

With my jquery I'm trying to make the transition from a message to a loading function easy on the eyes by animate the opasity of the message out, inserting the loading.gif and animating the opacity back in. It fails.

```
$('#powerSearchSubmitButton').click(function(ev) {
    startLoad();
    return false;
});
function startLoad() {
    $('.message').each(function(i) {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function() {
            $(this).html("<img src=\"/content/pics/loadingBig.gif\" alt=\"loading\" style=\"opacity:0\"/>");
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1},500);
        });
    };
    return true;
};
```

When I leave out the `.html()` call, it works fine (except off course the image is not there; So I think that it is beacuse the html isn't inserted with `opacity:0;` But when I inserted it with `style="opacity:0"` it cannot fade back in...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
     $(this).html("<img src='content/pics/loadingBig.gif' alt='loading'/>");
    });
$(this).fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the code I would use, except I have had issues where the fadeIn() starts before the inside html has been fully rendered.  To solve that I put the fadeIn() *inside* the fadeOut()'s callback function, immediately after the .html() method.

Comment: Yes, if you check previous answers you can see that I tried that.
It still gives me an IN YOUR FACE load of the loading gif in all browsers but FF

Answer (score 0):

Apply the animation to a container instead, or use the .css() method to set the opacity (inline styles might interfere with jQuery's ability to animate the corresponding properties).

Comment: the animation already IS on a container ( div with class "message").

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the image style="opacity:0;" - it wont be visible while it's parent is hidden, and, as you've found out, it will remain at 0 opacity once the parent has faded back in.

You could also use jQuery's [fadeIn](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn) and [FadeOut](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut) functions instead of manually animating.

Comment: thanks, fadeIn and fadeOut are indeed exactly the same. Internally they use the same as I did there.